# Excel VBA Insert Character Between Number and Letter

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, string

I would like some VBA code that would allow me to detect if a string contains any instances of a number followed by a letter and then insert a new character between them. For example:

User enters the following string:

```
4x^2+3x
```

Function returns:

```
4*x^2+3*x
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, what did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
Sub Button2_Click()
    Range("D5").Value = FixString(Range("B4").Text, "*")
End Sub

Function FixString(sIn As String, sAdd As String) As String
    Dim sOut As String, sChNow As String, _
      nChNow As Integer, nChNext As String, _
      nLen As Integer
    nLen = Len(sIn)
    If nLen > 1 Then
        For i = 1 To nLen - 1
            sChNow = Mid(sIn, i, 1)
            sOut = sOut & sChNow
            nChNow = Asc(sChNow)
            nChNext = Asc(Mid(sIn, i + 1, 1))
            If ((nChNext >= 65 And nChNext <= 90) Or _
               (nChNext >= 97 And nChNext <= 122)) And _
               ((nChNow >= 48 And nChNow <= 57)) Then
                sOut = sOut & sAdd
            End If
        Next i
        FixString = sOut & Right(sIn, 1)
    Else
        FixString = sIn
    End If
End Function
```

Just edit the Button2_Click() sub routine to suit your situation.